# python for loop not return multiple dict

Tags: python, django

I want json response from `xml_parser` view.I am getting only one dict instead of multiple dict .. seems my for loop logic is wrong .. can you correct that for me..?

```
def xml_parser(request):
    for child in root.findall('GetAll'):
        for geoloc in child.iter('loc'):
            geoinfo = geoloc.attrib
            pprint.pprint(geoinfo)
    jsoninfo = json.dumps(geoinfo, ensure_ascii=False)
    return HttpResponse(jsoninfo, content_type='application/json')
```

Okay now pprint shows and this is the exact output i want

```
{'lat': '36.15900011', 'lon': '-115.17205183'}
{'lat': '36.15899561', 'lon': '-115.17276155'}
```

but the url `http://127.0.0.1:8000/parser` shows `{"lat": "36.15899561", "lon": "-115.17276155"}` And may i know why?

Comment: You can't have that exact output, because that's not valid JSON. Valid JSON has to be one single thing—a number, an object, an array, etc.—not two separate things. The closest to what you want would be an array that has those two objects in it, but it's not going to be (or to `pprint` as) the exact same thing you've output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assignment of `jsoninfo` is happening outside of the for-loop but the assignment of `geoinfo` is happening inside of it.  You need to aggregate all of the `geoloc.attrib` values into a list and convert this to json at the end:

```
def xml_parser(request):
    infos = []

    for child in root.findall('GetAll'):
        for geoloc in child.iter('loc'):
            infos.append(geoloc.attrib)

    jsoninfo = json.dumps(infos, ensure_ascii=False)
    return HttpResponse(jsoninfo, content_type='application/json')
```

This assumes you actually meant to output a single JSON object as your response instead of two encodings of independent objects separated by a newline character.

Comment: Of course that's going to give him a JSON array with two objects in it, not two separate top-level objects as he asked for (because what he asked for isn't valid JSON, so there's really no choice but to do it this way).

Comment: Right, I'm assuming he actually meant to output a single JSON object.

Comment: Oh ... that's giving me list right ? now to the output is `[{"lat": "36.15900011", "lon": "-115.17205183"}, {"lat": "36.15899561", "lon": "-115.17276155"}]` but seems like my jquery `console.debug(r.jsoninfo.lat+ ',' + r.jsoninfo.lon)` giving me this error . `r,jsoninfo undefined

Comment: That seems like a totally different issue, but I think what you probably want is `console.debug(r[0].lat + ',' + r[0].lon)`.  That will give you the first element in the JSON array if `r` is the decoded JSON object.  By the way, if you have a separate question about Javascript and handling AJAX responses, you should probably ask that in a different question.  Also, make sure you put in an honest effort towards solving the problem on your own before asking.  You'll learn more that way.

Comment: hm .. ok .. i ll take it from here.. honestly before asking i ll try hard to fix it ...

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting `geoinfo` every time in your loop.  You are not storing all the results.  Consider creating an empty list, appending to it, and sending that back as a response